# Get content with url confluence REST API

Tags: rest, curl, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Hi I have noticed several ways to get the content with the REST API. Although I was wondering if there is a way to get the content directly from the url without calling the space and title.

Meaning if I have `http://localhost:8080/display/TST/myPage`
Instead of doing this

`curl -u admin:admin -X GET "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content?title=myPage&spaceKey=TST" | python -mjson.tool`

I can use the url on the rest api.
Maybe something like this

`curl -u admin:admin -X GET "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/display/TST/myPage" | python -mjson.tool`

Is there a way to do this?

This is the documentation I have looked at

https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/#d3e865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; immediately below the section you linked to, there is a description of the version of this request which takes an article ID: [/rest/api/content/{id}](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/#d3e933). As long as you know the article ID, this is the easiest way.

Comment: How do I get the content ID for a specific wiki page?

Comment: Browse to Tools -> Page Info and you can read the ID out of the destination URL.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I already was on `Page Info` but didn't found it... I have not looked to the URL. :)

Comment: But this is not fetching attachments.

Comment: @KeyurPatel - please ask that as a new question.

Comment: I am using  /rest/api/content/{id} ,it doesn't return all content.any suggestion!

Comment: Check the “expand” query parameter. But maybe this warrants its own question.